# If $A$ is an infinite set and $b \notin A$, is the equivalence $A \sim A \bigcup \{b\}$ provable without the axiom of choice (i.e. in ZF)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> A set $A$ is said to be infinite if there is a surjection from $A$ to $\mathbb N_0$.

Let $A$ be infinite, and denote by $b$ some set that is not included in $A$. (Such a $b$ exists by the specification axiom). To prove the equivalence

$$A \sim A \bigcup \{b\} \tag{
1}$$

in elementary set theory, one usually uses the fact that $A$ has a countably infinite subset (whose universal existance depends on some kind of choice).

- ***Q:*** But can the equivalence in $(1)$ be proven in some other way, without the axiom of choice? More specifically, in the context of ZF without regularity?

I assume it cannot be done but I am not sure... I am still quite the novice when it comes to axiom of choice considerations, having begun only yesterday. If if it cannot be done, should I expect the impossibility to have an elementary proof? (Again, I think not but am unsure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The definition you're using is also known as *weakly Dedekind-infinite*, and the property you are trying to prove is equivalent to Dedekind-infinite.

If there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set, then there is one which is weakly Dedekind-infinite. To see this, note that if $A$ is Dedekind-finite, either it is weakly Dedekind-infinite, or else its power set can be mapped onto $\Bbb N_0$ (by mapping finite sets to their size and infinite sets to $0$).

Now we can use a theorem of Kuratowski that $A$ is weakly Dedekind-infinite if and only if its power set is Dedekind-*infinite*. Since $A$ was *not* weakly Dedekind-infinite, its power set is Dedekind-finite, but we also proved that it is weakly Dedekind-infinite.

Comment: Thank you! To be sure I understood you correctly... Firstly, the theorem candidate in OP is equivalent in ZF to saying that all weakly Dedekind-infinite sets are Dedekind-infinite. To show this equivalent form and thus the original form in the OP does not follow from ZF axioms, it therefore suffices to show a model of ZF exists where there is a set which is Dedekind-finite and yet also weakly Dedekind-infinite. (1/2)

Comment: Secondly, to achieve this goal, you show that if there is a model of ZF wherein there is an infinite set $A$ (in the sense of no bijections from $\{0, \dots, n - 1\}$ to the set $A$ for any natural $n$ nor is empty) which is also Dedekind-finite, then either $A$ itself or the power set of $A$ is the desired example which is Dedekind-finite and weakly Dedekind-infinite. Thirdly, I assume (having read in sometimes non-trustworthy Wiki) that there are models of ZF in which there is an infinite Dedekind-finite set. Thus we are done. Is this correct, or have I misunderstood something? (2/2)

Comment: What I'm saying is that $\sf ZF$ proves that "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" is in fact equivalent to "infinite implies D-infinite". And we know that neither is provable from ZF because we can find models (e.g. Cohen's original model where $\sf ZF+\lnot AC$ holds) where there is an infinite set which is not Dedekind-infinite.

Comment: Hah! I was hoping for a yes-no comment reply :-). Hmm. Isn't establishing the equivalence between "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" and "infinite implies D-infinite" in ZF a pedagogically unnecessary step? You hint that there is a model of ZF wherein an infinite D-finite set $A$ exists, and you prove that in ZF this implies either $A$ or its power set is simultaneously weakly D-infinite and D-finite. Surely this already proves that the equivalence "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" is unprovable in ZF. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it's an unnecessary step, but it clarifies the picture.

Comment: (Also, the next question about "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" is whether or not this can be separated from "infinite implies D-infinite", so I'm preemptively answering any followups by you, or by future readers.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It's not immediately obvious to me that "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" implies "infinite implies D-infinite" in ZF, I guess that was also a reason to skip it! (The converse, of course, is clear because weakly D-infinite implies infinite in ZF). I'll think about it in the morning. In the meantime, thanks again for your answer which I will now accept. Would you dare to recommend any source (for a novice) you particularly like to get into the Cohen model-related topics?

Comment: About the "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" implies "infinite implies D-infinite". Let $A$ be an infinite set. It suffices to show that $A$ is weakly D-infinite. An infinite set will have subsets of every finite size by induction, so $P(A)$ is weakly D-infinite, and so D-infinite by assumption. By Kuratowski, $A$ must therefore be weakly D-infinite. I assume this is the argument you had in mind?

Comment: But not every infinite set is weakly D-infinite. The point is that if $A$ is infinite D-finite, then its power set is either Dedekind-infinite, in which case $A$ was weakly D-infinite, or else the power set itself is weakly D-infinite, but not D-infinite. (And that is the essence of Kuratowski's theorem.)

Comment: I agree with you that not every infinite set is weakly D-infinite (in ZF). My last comment was simply to make sure I understood the $\Longrightarrow$-direction of the statement ' "weakly D-infinite implies D-infinite" is in fact equivalent to "infinite implies D-infinite" ' from your earlier comment. I believe we can now conclude our discussion here, unless you disagree. Thank you again for your insight on this matter!

Comment: You're very welcome!